# Magento 2 - Limit Filter Items

Tags: magento2, category, attributes, layered-navigation

On my category pages I'm using 2 filters, Category and Price.  What I would like to do is limit the number of filterable items under Category to 10 items.  I'm looking in `magento/module-layered-navigation/view/frontend/templates/layer/filter.phtml` where all of the filter items are being looped through, but I'm not quite sure how to limit the items JUST for "Category".  This template handles all of the filter items so I don't want to limit filters other than "Category".

Comment: Able to manage using  `vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\navigation\left.phtml`?